# onchange event not working for notifications permission in SW for firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, push-notification, service-worker, navigator

I recently added a notification part for our web application and it's working fine on chrome and opera, but for firefox, initially, I got an error with this message:

> The Notification permission may only be requested from inside a short running user-generated event handler.

So, I added a button for granting the notifications permission and now I find out there is a bigger bug; the 'onchange' event of navigator.permissions not working to activate notifications after getting permission from the user. here is my code:

```
self.addEventListener('activate', async () => { 
   if ('permissions' in navigator) { // inside of this if not executing on firefox
       navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'notifications' }).then(function (permissionStatus) {
           permissionStatus.onchange = function () {
            // do thing in here...
           };
      });
   }
   //...
});
```

Although I know 'window' is the default variable in js files, I also tried 'window.navigator' instead of 'navigator' and nothing changed.

Comment: For anyone having the same issue, it's a bug in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1754372

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found out since we are triggering ask permission by hand and by clicking on a button, the firefox mechanism is different and we should do our onchange action as a result of the permission request promise just like below:

```
      Notification.requestPermission()
     .then(async result => {
        if (result === 'granted') {
           // subscribe and do stuff in here...
        }
     })
     .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
     });
```

You can still use the explained onchange method for other browsers like chrome.